# A RenderFlex overflowed by 21 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gridview, flutter-layout

I'm newbie in the flutter and I try use Grid View but it shows a render flex overflowed by 21 pixels on the bottom. In the GridView I'm using picture, but it shows error. Anyone know how to fix it? Thank you

I search on the internet, it use SingleChildScrollView, but I don't want to use it because it looks weird for the Grid view

Here my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/detail.dart';

class BudgetSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BudgetSettingsState createState() => _BudgetSettingsState();
}

class _BudgetSettingsState extends State<BudgetSettings> {
  List<Container> categorylist = new List();

  var character=[
    {"name":"Food", "image":"food.png"},
    {"name":"Social-Life", "image":"travel.png"},
    {"name":"Transportation", "image":"transportation.png"},
    {"name":"Beauty", "image":"makeup.png"},
    {"name":"Household", "image":"household.png"},
    {"name":"Education", "image":"education.png"},
    {"name":"Health", "image":"health.png"},
    {"name":"Gift", "image":"gift.png"},
    {"name":"Other", "image":"other.png"},
  ];
  _makelist() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
      final newcharacter = character[i];
      final String image = newcharacter["image"];
      categorylist.add(
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new Card( child:
            new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image.asset('assets/$image', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                    new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),),
                    new Text(newcharacter['name'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
            )
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _makelist();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Budget Setting'),
      ),

      body: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: categorylist,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here my output[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for your problem is wrapping your image widget inside a Flexible widget, just like this:

```
Flexible(
  child: Image.asset('assets/$image', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
),
```